# Submit comment by pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, meteor

I am making a chat app with Meteor using this tutorial (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-messaging-for-meteor-with-meteor-streams--net-33409) and I am stuck at trying to make it where if you press enter it submits your comment instead of having to press the Send button everytime.

Below is the javascript code the app uses to submit a comment by pressing the Send button, but does anyone know what code I need to put in to be able to submit a comment by pressing enter?

```
// when Send Chat clicked add the message to the collection
Template.chatBox.events({
  "click #send": function() {
    var message = $('#chat-message').val();
    chatCollection.insert({
     userId: 'me',
     message: message
   });
   $('#chat-message').val('');

   //add the message to the stream
   chatStream.emit('chat', message);
  }
});
chatStream.on('chat', function(message) {
  chatCollection.insert({
    userId: this.userId,
    subscriptionId: this.subscriptionId,
    message: message
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the `keypress` event and take the same action therein:

```
 function sendMessage() {
   var message = $('#chat-message').val();
    chatCollection.insert({
     userId: 'me',
     message: message
   });
   $('#chat-message').val('');

   //add the message to the stream
   chatStream.emit('chat', message);
  }

  Template.chatBox.events({
      // Capture the `keyup` event on the `input` element.
      "keyup input": function(ev) {
        if(ev.which === 13) {  // If it was an enter key
          sendMessage();
        }
      },
      "click #send": function () { sendMessage(); }
    });
```

Comment: Would I add this right after the existing code that I had in my original post? I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3330382 No, you would replace your code you have pased with this. Also, you may need to catch the `keyup` event on `textarea` if you want to follow the tutorial to the word.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to place your form in a `<form>`-element, and get this functionality for free if you use an `<input>`-element instead of a `<textarea>`-element (if I wrote text in a `<textarea>`-element that submitted the form when I pressed enter I would go crazy!). Just listen for the forms `submit` event.

Comment: Don't forget to preventDefault in the submit callback